# Prove that $a/(p-a) + b/(p-b) + c/(p-c) \ge 6$

Tags: geometry, inequality

Prove that $a/(p-a) + b/(p-b) + c/(p-c) \ge 6$ , where $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle and $p$ is the semi-perimeter .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to set $p-a=s_1, p-b=s_2, p-c=s_3$. $a,b,c$ are triangle sides iff $s_i>0$ and your inequality can be written as
$$ \left(\frac{s_1}{s_2}+\frac{s_2}{s_1}\right)+\left(\frac{s_1}{s_3}+\frac{s_3}{s_1}\right)+\left(\frac{s_3}{s_2}+\frac{s_2}{s_3}\right)\geq 6 $$
that is trivial since $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$ for any $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $p = \dfrac{a+b+c}{2} > 0$, and observe the function $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{p-x}$ on $0 < x < p$ is convex. thus $3f\left(\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}\right)\le f(a) + f(b) + f(c)$, and the left hand side of this equality is precisely $6$, thus we have the proof.

Answer (score 0):

By C-S $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{p-a}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(pa-a^2)}=\frac{2(a+b+c)^2}{(a+b+c)^2-2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}\geq\frac{2(a+b+c)^2}{(a+b+c)^2-\frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)^2}=6$